# Python requests [Errno 111] Connection refused when running on server, but not on local PC

Tags: python, python-requests, urllib3

I have a web scraper script which runs fine on my (Windows) PC, but I'm trying to get it to run from a (Linux) web server. I have a number of other scripts which run fine on the server (connecting to different websites than this one), but when I run this script, I get a `[Errno 111] Connection refused` error.

Here is a minimal version of the script to demonstrate the problem:

```
import time
import requests
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

s = requests.Session()

target = "http://taxsearch.co.grayson.tx.us:8443/"
headers = {"Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8",
           "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate",
           "Accept-Language": "en",
           "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
           "Connection": "keep-alive",
           "Host": "taxsearch.co.grayson.tx.us:8443",
           "Pragma": "no-cache",
           "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests": "1",
           "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.121 Safari/537.36"
}


time.sleep(1)
response = s.get(target, headers=headers)

if response.status_code == requests.codes.ok:
    results = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')

    # Do something with output
else:
    response.raise_for_status()
```

This runs fine on my PC, but when running on the server, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jken/virtualenv/web-scraper/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 159, in _new_conn
    (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
  File "/home/jken/virtualenv/web-scraper/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 80, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/home/jken/virtualenv/web-scraper/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 70, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jken/virtualenv/web-scraper/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 600, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/home/jken/virtualenv/web-scraper/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 354, in _make_request
    conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
  File "/opt/alt/python36/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
    self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
  File "/opt/alt/python36/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1285, in _send_request
    self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/opt/alt/python36/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1234, in endheaders
    self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
  File "/opt/alt/python36/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1026, in _send_output
    self.send(msg)
  File "/opt/alt/python36/lib64/python3.6/http/client.py", line 964, in send
    self.connect()
  File "/home/jken/virtualenv/web-scraper/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 181, in connect
    conn = self._new_conn()
  File "/home/jken/virtualenv/web-scraper/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 168, in _new_conn
    self, "Failed to establish a new connection: %s" % e)
urllib3.exceptions.NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x2af700598c18>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/jken/virtualenv/web-scraper/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 449, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/home/jken/virtualenv/web-scraper/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 638, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/home/jken/virtualenv/web-scraper/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 398, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='taxsearch.co.grayson.tx.us', port=8443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x2af700598c18>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "../python/grayson-2year.py", line 22, in <module>
    response = s.get(target, headers=headers)
  File "/home/jken/virtualenv/web-scraper/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 546, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jken/virtualenv/web-scraper/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 533, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/home/jken/virtualenv/web-scraper/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/sessions.py", line 646, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/home/jken/virtualenv/web-scraper/3.6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 516, in send
    raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='taxsearch.co.grayson.tx.us', port=8443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x2af700598c18>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

My guess would be that the issue here is down to some firewall issue on the webserver or something, but I'm really not sure. Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: you server don't allow programs to direct connectivity to internet, add proxy if you have one

Comment: @ZigmaEmpire I have other scripts that use the requests module to connect to different websites which work fine on the server. It seems this issue is specific to this website/port. Would a proxy still fix this?

Comment: you can try putting some other public host address like https://stackoverflow.com and test to know that, may be you need to check the ip tables which allows the outgoing ports, yes adding a proxy could solve your problem

Comment: Check if you are properly connected to the internet!